# find the Laplace transform of the following $f(t)=(\sqrt{t}-1)^{2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, laplace-transform, constants

find the Laplace transform of the following question

$f(t)=(\sqrt{t}-1)^{2}$

Comment: Consider it done.

Comment: [What is a PSQ?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33854/what-is-a-psq)